# Visual Studio 2012, C++ cout builds but doesn't open command prompt and display

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, cout

On a fresh install of Windows 7 64-bit, through bootcamp on my MacBook Pro.

Visual Studio 2012 installed. In a proper .cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "Hello World" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

This builds successfully but I get no display of "Hello World" anywhere. No command prompt window pops up, either.

I checked linker in the configuration and "SUBSYSTEM" is set to "CONSOLE". Anything else it could be?

Comment: Are you sure you ran it?

Comment: By what means are you attempting to execute it?

Comment: Did you create a Win32 console application?

Comment: @abhinole, With the subsystem set to console, it should be good.

Comment: Wait, you said VS2012, but tagged it VS2010. Not that it *should* make a difference, but I'm just pointing it out.

Comment: @chris my bad on the tag, yes I'm in VS2012. I'm building with project-> build solution, and running with Fn + F5

Comment: @abinhole I just created the Win32 Console Application and it worked! Thank you very much guys